# fair rating for my current movie database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rating

Ok hopefully my last post regarding the movie rating system I am trying to program. Thanks to user Asaph for helping me with my top 5 goring films. This is my database layout:

```
  ID | UserID | Rating | TMDB |  TYPE
  -----------------------------------
   1      34        6     432      2
  -----------------------------------
   2      34        9     432      3
  -----------------------------------
   3      44        9     468      2
```

and using this sql I can list the top gorey films (type 2)

```
sql SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM `tbl_rating`
WHERE `type`= :type
GROUP BY `tmdb`
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Now I was wondering is there a way I can make this more fair on my movie results?

for example movie123 might have 5 votes with an avg vote 7 and movie456 might only have 1 vote but if its above 7 it will be on the top of the list. How can i make this more fair? maybe somehow doing a min number of rows in group? or any other way?

Again any help is amazing!

Comment: I think its something like
        $sql = 'SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rate) AS avg_rating, COUNT(rate) AS min_count FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `type`= :type AND min_count > 4 GROUP BY `tmdb` ORDER BY avg_rating DESC LIMIT 5'; but this doesnt work for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think this is what I wanted to do :)

```
$sql = 'SELECT `tmdb`, AVG(rate) AS avg_rating, COUNT(rate) AS min_count FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `type`= :type GROUP BY `tmdb` HAVING min_count > 1 ORDER BY avg_rating DESC LIMIT 5';
```

this seems to do the trick if there is a better way feel free to let me know :)